# Index not used on group by count

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, postgresql-14

I have this kind of table and index

```
create table dlq_data (
    id           VARCHAR(256)            not null
        primary key,
    data         JSONB                   not null,
    publish_time TIMESTAMP               not null,
    resubmitted  BOOLEAN   default false,
    created_at   TIMESTAMP default now() not null,
    message_id   VARCHAR(256)
);

create index dlq_data__message_id__idx
    on dlq_data using hash(message_id);

create index dlq_data_optimized_idx
    on dlq_data((data ->> 'root'::TEXT), (data ->> 'payloadType'::TEXT));
```

but when i tried to run group by query, the index not being used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT data->>'root', data->>'payloadType', count(1)
         FROM dlq_data
         GROUP BY data->>'root', data->>'payloadType';

Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=2271510.76..2271845.74 rows=1272 width=72)
  Group Key: ((data ->> 'root'::text)), ((data ->> 'payloadType'::text))
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=2271510.76..2271807.58 rows=2544 width=72)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Sort  (cost=2270510.73..2270513.91 rows=1272 width=72)
              Sort Key: ((data ->> 'root'::text)), ((data ->> 'payloadType'::text))
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=2270426.06..2270445.14 rows=1272 width=72)
                    Group Key: (data ->> 'root'::text), (data ->> 'payloadType'::text)
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on dlq_data  (cost=0.00..2231090.71 rows=5244714 width=64)
```

it only used on where query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dlq_data
WHERE data->>'root' = '' AND data->>'playloadType' = ''

Aggregate  (cost=22067.44..22067.45 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dlq_data  (cost=67.30..22067.37 rows=28 width=0)
        Recheck Cond: ((data ->> 'root'::text) = ''::text)
        Filter: ((data ->> 'playloadType'::text) = ''::text)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dlq_data_optimized_idx  (cost=0.00..67.30 rows=5698 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((data ->> 'root'::text) = ''::text)
```

also not for `<>`:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM dlq_data
WHERE data->>'root' <> '' AND data->>'playloadType' <> '';

Finalize Aggregate  (cost=2271354.81..2271354.82 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Gather  (cost=2271354.59..2271354.80 rows=2 width=8)
        Workers Planned: 2
        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=2270354.59..2270354.60 rows=1 width=8)
              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on dlq_data  (cost=0.00..2257314.27 rows=5216128 width=0)
                    Filter: (((data ->> 'root'::text) <> ''::text) AND ((data ->> 'playloadType'::text) <> ''::text))
```

what index should be created for that group by count?

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your statements? That gives us way more information than just explain.

Comment: Why would it be? If you are grouping by `data->>'root', data->>'payloadType';` you would need to scan the entire table to determine the combinations.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i assume if it's already on index it should only scan from index, since everything needed from the query already on index, just need to count it.

Comment: adding analyze would take hours '__') @FrankHeikens

Comment: You assume wrong, see [Slow Counting](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting).

Comment: Why would it take hours? How many TB is your table?

Comment: only around 20GB but bunch of writes, and maybe slow disk @FrankHeikens

Comment: 20GB takes just a few minutes when your system does only 100MB per second, and that's slow nowadays. A 7200 RPM HDD offers that kind of speeds. If your query takes hours to execute, there must be something else going on

Answer (score 1):

You could get an index scan just by disabling the seq scan, `set enable_seqscan = off`. That is unlikely to be an improvement, though.

You could get an index-only scan if you make the index on `((data ->> 'root'::TEXT), (data ->> 'payloadType'::TEXT), data)` but "data" might be too large to be accommodated in full in the index.  There is no fundamentally good reason for this restriction (that "data" itself needs to be in the index), it is just that no one has bothered to code around the issue.